# What is this hand written, abbreviated month?

Tags: 20th-century, palaeography, bible

I have a death section of a family bible and I'm having trouble reading it:

[image]

The entry for James B Scott died <s>Feb</s> *?Sep?* 21, 1953.

Is that month September, April, or another month in 1953?  The first letter does not look like the `S` from Scott surname, so maybe an `A` like in the August on next line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that it reads Ap. for April, and that the A in Ap. is very similar to the A in Aug on the line below.

I do not think that it reads Sep. because the S would look unlike any of the five distinctive examples of that letter from the same page.

I cannot be certain but I think the correction is written by the same hand using the same pen, and probably at or soon after the same time.

I think it would be useful to see if you can confirm that death date using one or more other sources like a death/funeral notice in a newspaper, if not a death certificate.